# React : Change in node_modules file does not reflect the change in UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Maybe I am doing it wrong. I want to do changes in node_modules folder. Now when I run npm run watch or npm run dev it doesn't get reflected in UI.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: can you elaborate the changes you want in 'node_modules' and share the package.json with the scripts for 'watch' and 'dev'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try editing from the /dist folder of the library you are trying to edit. Your changes will not reflect if you edit from the source and not from the output bundles.

Note: If you are just logging a result (via console.log) that is fine, but as much as possible, do not edit from the node_modules folder.